# Does creating an SKPhysicsJoint between two SKPhysicsBody objects disable collision detection between them?

Tags: ios7, box2d-iphone, sprite-kit

I've noticed the following:

1. If I create a scene with physics boundaries (`bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect`) and two nodes each with a circular solid physics body (`bodyWithCircleOfRadius`), upon adding these 2 nodes to the scene, they can collide with each other and with the scene's bounds, as expected.
2. If I add any type of joint between the two nodes however, the joint constraint holds between them and they can both still collide against the scene's bounds. But they no longer collide with each other.

This seems like a bug to me. I'd expect that any joints between physics bodies would be in addition to their basic collision mechanism. Has anyone experienced similar behavior or has any hints as to what might I be doing wrong?

(BTW, the reason why I'm tagging this with Box2d is because SpriteKit uses Box2d, so this might be a box2d known issue that I'm unaware of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is Box2D default behavior. I believe in box2d you can override it, but it's recommended not to. The reason is that colliding bodies on a joint will fight against the joint limits and vice versa, introducing instability in the simulation. The result being that the two bodies fighting to resolve both their joint constraints and their collision response introduces additional forces.

Comment: Thanks. But then, how do you model in box2D something like, say, 2 balls attached by a rope?

Comment: I suppose you'd use the rope joint but that isn't included in Sprite Kit unfortunately.

Comment: It is: SKPhysicsJointLimit, and it is indeed the type of joint I'm using. But the problem is, it only has maxLength, so two nodes constrained thru it cannot move apart further than maxLength but can still move together as much as they want and intersect with each other, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Right now I'm anchoring the joint on the nodes' centers though. Maybe I should anchor them to an edge of their bounds instead?